# Is there any gdb-multiarch for macOS?

Tags: terminal, homebrew

I'm on macOS Monterey (x64). I already have [gdb](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/gdb) installed, and by reading [it's formula](https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula/gdb.json), seems like it only supports x86_64. What about ARM64?

This is what I'm trying to do: https://mariokartwii.com/armv8/ch21.html, which is building and running ARM64 assembly code with QEMU and GDB. No issue on building the code, and running it with qemu (there is `qemu-system-aarc64` available). The issue is running this part:

```
gdb-multiarch -q --nh \
  -ex 'set architecture aarch64' \
  -ex 'file hello_world' \
  -ex 'target remote localhost:1234' \
  -ex 'layout split' \
  -ex 'layout regs'
```

Where can I find the binary of `gdb-multiarch` for macOS? Not a problem if you are running Linux, e.g https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=gdb-multiarch

Comment: You probably can compile gdb yourself instead of installing the Homebrew version (or modify the formula to build the multiarch version and then rebuild locally).